# How to create files with names from array?

Tags: ruby

```
array = ["Cliebnt.rb", "Clientversbion.txt", "filbe1.rb", "UpdateSebrver.rb", "ttesbt.rb",     "filbe2.txt", "readebr.rb", "Actualbversion.txt"]
print a = array.size
a.times do
print  b = array.pop
 sleep 2
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(File.new (b)))
end
```

its return

```
"txtfile1.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - Actualbversion.txt (Errno::ENOENT)"
```

How fix it?

Comment: In what directory you want to create it ? `"Actualbversion.txt"` not created, thus throwing error. Why you need `chdir` ?

Comment: in the dir with this .rb-sile. I can't set the dir to this script. try to use just some like this - File.new (b), but again return err

Comment: You can, the way you are trying is wrong.. Tell me which directory you want.

Comment: I need to create these files in the same directory where the script

Comment: The directory where the script is located is `File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))`.

Answer (score 0):

something like bellow may work for you :

```
Dir.chdir(__dir__) do |path|
  array.each { |file| File.new(file) }
end
```

Look the doc of [`__dir__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) and [`Dir::chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).